# How to make listofalgorithms behave like a section, not a chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, algorithms

I have a problem. I included the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,reqno]{book} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

and wanted to create a `\listofalgorithms` but not as chapter; I want it as section.
I tried the following:

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{}
\section*{Algorithmenverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Algorithmenverzeichnis}
\listofalgorithms
```

But then the title and the list are not on the same page even with the command `\begin{samepage}\end{samepage}` around or `\nopagebreak` in between.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporarily change `\chapter` into `\section`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Algorithmenverzeichnis}
\let\chapter\section
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The grouping above limits the scope of the redefinition(s). As such `\chapter` becomes `\section` only until `\endgroup`.